# req.body is undefined with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I want to implement AJAX using express and jquery.

`index.ejs`

```
<script>
const increment = () => {
    let value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('number').value) <== returns correct number
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick='increment()'>add</button>
<form action="/dash" method="POST" id="mon">
    <input id="number" name='number' value=<%=money %>>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

`index.js`

```
router.post('/dash', isLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const num = req.body.number;
    const filter = {username: req.user.username};
    const update = {money: num};
    await User.updateOne(filter, update);
    console.log(num) <== also returns correct number
    res.redirect('/dash')
})
```

And that, when alone (without jquery), is working perfectly, it returns the right number and save it to db.

The problem arises when I add jquery code to the script.

JQuery code in `index.ejs`'s `script` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#mon").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $('input[name=number]').val();
            console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'dash',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'text',
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    var num = $('input[name=number]').val();
                    console.log(num)
                    $('input[name=number]').val(num);
                });
        });
    });
```

And basically it also works, it won't refresh the page when the button is clicked, but now the `console.log(req.body.number)` in `index.js` returns undefined, and it won't save in db.

Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form data consists of a series of key=value pairs.

You have:

```
var data = $('input[name=number]').val();
```

So the data you are sending is **one** value with **no** keys.

You need:

```
var data = {
    number: $('input[name=number]').val();
};
```